# Unable to create instance of converter RuntimeException

Tags: java, json, jackson, versioning, runtimeexception

I am considering to use [Jackson Model Versioning Module](https://github.com/jonpeterson/jackson-module-model-versioning) created by @jon-peterson in my project, so I am creating a test Java project so I can check how it works.

It's a basic project which has a Car class and I add a Versioned Model. The versioned model converter is an empty funcion, I just want the project to be executed successfully. When I run it, I get a **RuntimeException**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to create instance of converter 'ToCurrentCarConverter'
at com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersionedModelDeserializer.<init>(VersionedModelDeserializer.java:58)
at com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersioningBeanDeserializationModifier.createVersioningDeserializer(VersioningBeanDeserializationModifier.java:37)
at com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersioningBeanDeserializationModifier.modifyDeserializer(VersioningBeanDeserializationModifier.java:46)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:251)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:137)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:411)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:477)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4178)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3997)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
at Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersionedModelDeserializer cannot access a member of class ToCurrentCarConverter with modifiers ""
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:376)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:647)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:490)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
at com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersionedModelDeserializer.<init>(VersionedModelDeserializer.java:56)
... 14 more
```

**Car class**

```
import com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.JsonVersionedModel;

import java.util.List;

@JsonVersionedModel(currentVersion = "1.0", toCurrentConverterClass = ToCurrentCarConverter.class)
public class Car {

private int seats;
private String brand;
private List<String> features;

public Car(){}

public Car(int seats, String brand, List<String> features){
    this.seats = seats;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.features = features;
}

public int getSeats() {
    return seats;
}

public void setSeats(int seats) {
    this.seats = seats;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public List<String> getFeatures() {
    return features;
}

public void setFeatures(List<String> features) {
    this.features = features;
}

}
```

**Car converter**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersionedModelConverter;

class ToCurrentCarConverter implements VersionedModelConverter {
@Override
public ObjectNode convert(ObjectNode objectNode, String modelVersion, String targetModelVersion,
                          JsonNodeFactory jsonNodeFactory) {
    return objectNode;
}
}
```

*Main*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.github.jonpeterson.jackson.module.versioning.VersioningModule;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    mapper.registerModule(new VersioningModule());

    List<String> features = new ArrayList<String>();
    features.add("feature1");
    features.add("feature2");
    features.add("feature3");
    Car car = new Car(5, "Ford", features);

    String carString = "";

    try {
        carString = mapper.writeValueAsString(car);
        System.out.println(carString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Car readCar = mapper.readValue(carString, Car.class);
        System.out.println(readCar.getBrand());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```